# How to restore the Build window in Android Studio 4.1

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I recently upgraded to Android Studio 4.1 and in the process it also did a Kotlin and Command Line Tools update. After everything finished, my "Build" window was missing from the bottom and there's no way to open it because "View->Tool Windows->Build" is also missing.

Once I do a "Make Project", however, the Build window appears at the bottom and the "Tool Window" menu item for "Build" returns. But if I exit the IDE and return, they're both gone again.

How did this happen, and is there a way to restore the Build window and associated menu item so they're always present, like before?

Answer (score -1):

If I'm not mistaken, you should check `Window` -> `Background tasks` -> `Show`/`Auto show`

Comment: I was hopeful, but sadly that didn't fix it.